# Flutter - Async method in Navigator callback refresh screen

Tags: async-await, dart, flutter, future

I have a Navigator.push like this:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "NovoCNPJ").then((value) {
                    setState(() {
                      setupList();
                    });
                  });
```

And i need to update my *list* variable with this setState, my setupList method:

```
setupList() async {
    var banco = await db.initDB();
    list = await banco.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Empresa');
    return list;
  }
```

This method is async and so I think it is not running on this code. When i come back from the last screen, the setupList should be activated and reloaded my list with the new item, but the method isn't called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `async` is the problem, Can you try this ?

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "NovoCNPJ").then((value) async {
  var banco = await db.initDB();
  var tempList = await banco.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Empresa');
  setState(() {
    list = tempList
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "NovoCNPJ").then((value) async {
  var banco = await db.initDB();
  var tempList = await banco.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Empresa');
  setState(() {
    list = new List();
    listArray = new List();
    list = new List.from(tempList);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey, i solved the problem in a similar way, i edited your answer. Thanks Dinesh!

Comment: Sorry, I skipped to your edit. `banco.rawQuery ` should give a `new List`. Do we have to create another one ?